# Adding to a list in javaScript through HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my script there is a list of words that populate a grid dynamically.

Is there a way to fill the list with the words that populate the grid through HTML?

I have this at the moment...

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog"];
```

Is there a way to add more words in this list through HTML rather than in the script?

I ask because new words need to be added by colleges that can deal with HTML but not script

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you could create an HTML structure that would create a DOM that could be parsed by JavaScript which would extract text from between certain elements (e.g. list items) and append those strings to the array.

… teaching people the very simple array syntax would be easier though.

… as would using a text file with one entry per line.

Comment: Could I have a list of divs in the HTML that hold the words and a method in the script to pull them out into the list, to then populate the grid? @Quentin

Comment: What would be your suggestion, bearing in mind that I cannot teach them the array syntax because I have been told so? @Quentin

Comment: @m0onio — Yes. A div wouldn't be as semantically appropriate as a list, but it would work in exactly the same way.

Comment: @m0onio — I'd suggest replacing management with one that recognised that learning JS array syntax is easier then writing HTML.

Comment: One last thing is that it wont randomize when I change the number to be produced? @Quentin

Comment: @m0onio — So make use of the array's `length` property

Comment: I changed slice(0, 6) to (0,3) and nothing happened? @Quentin

Comment: Why would it? You don't do anything with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is able to write this in html:

```
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hey</li>
</ul>
```

You can add them to list of words with:

```
[].push.apply( listOfWords, $("ul li").map( function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get() );

console.log( listOfWords );
//["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "hello", "hi", "hey"]
```

Though I can't understand how could they not be able to write:

```
["hello", "hi", "hey"]
```